# Access parameters set from another node

Tags: ros, ros2, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using ROS2 Bouncy.

I have two nodes. What I would like to do is to allow the first node to set some parameters on the parameters server and then make the second node to retrieve these parameters.

The problem is that I'm able to see the parameters only from the node that has set them.

NODE 1

```
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("node_1");

  rclcpp::SyncParametersClient::SharedPtr parameters_client = std::make_shared<rclcpp::SyncParametersClient>(node);

  while (!parameters_client->wait_for_service(1s)){ 
     if (!rclcpp::ok()) { 
         RCLCPP_ERROR(node->get_logger(), "Interrupted while waiting for the service. Exiting.");
         return 0;}
    RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "service not available, waiting again..."); }

  std::vector<rcl_interfaces::msg::SetParametersResult> set_parameters_results = parameters_client->set_parameters({rclcpp::Parameter("wheels.radius", 1)});

  rclcpp::spin(node);
  rclcpp::shutdown();
```

NODE 2

```
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("node_2");

  rclcpp::SyncParametersClient::SharedPtr parameters_client = std::make_shared<rclcpp::SyncParametersClient>(node);

  while (!parameters_client->wait_for_service(1s)){ 
     if (!rclcpp::ok()) { 
         RCLCPP_ERROR(node->get_logger(), "Interrupted while waiting for the service. Exiting.");
         return 0;}
    RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "service not available, waiting again..."); }

    rclcpp::spin_some(node);

    auto parameters_and_prefixes = parameters_client->list_parameters({ }, 0);
    std::cout<<"READING PARAMS"<<std::endl;
    for (auto & name : parameters_and_prefixes.names) {
        std::cout<<"P: "<< name << std::endl;
    }
```

The `parameters_and_prefixes` variable in the second node is an empty vector. On the other hand, if I try to list all parameters from node 1 (where they are actually set), everything works fine.

It looks like I'm setting the parameters for node 1 only... What should I change ?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306094/access-parameters-set-from-another-node/) by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1322 on 2018-10-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the issue is that in `NODE 2` you're not providing a remote node name:

http://docs.ros2.org/bouncy/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1_sync_parameters_client.html#ad7d9189ce6b12fbe0d23890ed61bb928

(it's the second argument after the handle to the local node)

Basically that defaults to `""` which implicitly means "this node", which I admit isn't very clear.

So yes, in `NODE 2` you're listing parameters on yourself rather than `NODE 1`.

Try this change in `NODE 2`:

```
auto parameters_client = std::make_shared<rclcpp::SyncParametersClient>(node, "node_1");
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-10-17**:
Thank you for the clarification! Is there a way to have some sort of global parameters? Which can be accessed even without knowing which node has created them? They can still live within one node and have its lifetime, but I really would like to throw away the node name from the method..

**Comment by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on 2018-10-17**:
For global parameters, from what I see [here](https://design.ros2.org/articles/ros_parameters.html), I don't think it will be possible:
*For the sake of validating parameter lifecycle, all parameters will be hosted on a node. Their lifetime will be implicitly tied to the nodes lifetime.*

**Comment by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on 2018-10-17**:
Nm, forget my previous comment, if you read a bit further it says : *Backwards compatibility Parameter Server like behavior [...] To this end we propose to write a simple node which emulates the policy of the ROS 1.0 parameter server: it runs in namespace / and simply accepts all changes requested.*

**Comment by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on 2018-10-17**:
It was the proposed approach though, so I don't know what has been implemented yet or if it changed.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-10-17**:
There's no global parameters right now. We have always talked about having a special node that accepts all parameter changes and maybe some convenience functions in `rclcpp` for accessing it, but we haven't done that yet.

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-10-25**:
@William is setting the remote node to `""` and then setting/getting parameters equivalent to use the methods `Node::set_parameters`, `Node::get_parameters` defined here https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/master/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/node.cpp#L122 ?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-10-25**:
Yup! In fact I've considered removing the ability to use the parameter client on "self", but it's useful for tests.

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-10-25**:
@William Thanks! If I do not create a parameter client on "self" can I still register a `rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterEvent` callback for the parameters owned by this node? Despite the name, it looks to me that `register_param_change_callback` should be used for accepting/rejecting changes only

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-10-25**:
You can use (misuse?) `register_param_change_callback` http://docs.ros2.org/bouncy/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1_node.html#aed9fcbbe42dbe03008ae4bfcfa0452f0 to monitor what changes are requested (and just accept them all), but you can also just make a subscriber to the parameter event's topic.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-10-25**:
We should probably have a way to get a callback for each "parameter event" which works locally without any ROS mechanisms in place (no topics or services).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can give a `remote_node_name` when creating a `SyncParametersClient`:

```
SyncParametersClient(
    rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node,
    const std::string & remote_node_name = "",
    const rmw_qos_profile_t & qos_profile = rmw_qos_profile_parameters)
```

So in NODE 1 you can do :

```
rclcpp::SyncParametersClient::SharedPtr parameters_client = std::make_shared<rclcpp::SyncParametersClient>(node, "node2");
```

edit: If you want to catch parameter changes during run time, you might want to play with parameters events.
Because from what I tried (very quickly, might be wrong), NODE 1 is going to wait for NODE 2 to be launched at `while (!parameters_client->wait_for_service(1s))`. So you'll have to launch NODE 2 first but then in NODE 2 you only check parameters once in the main and since NODE 1 hasn't set them yet, you won't receive them.

edit 2: Just in case, you can find examples about this in the [demos](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/master/demo_nodes_cpp/src/parameters) pkg.

---

Originally posted by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) with karma: 203 on 2018-10-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-10-17**:
^ What he said :D

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-10-17**:
Thank you, it works, but I don't think I can use it in more general cases where there is more than one node willing to read the parameters. Moreover I need to hardcode `node2` which is something that I could not know while writing the code for node1. Maybe I need a `ParameterService` ?

**Comment by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on 2018-10-17**:
Oh yeah, the other option is to set the parameter on NODE 1 for NODE 1, so don't change what you did in NODE 1 but use what @William said

```
auto parameters_client = std::make_shared<rclcpp::SyncParametersClient>(node, "node_1");
```

in NODE 2, NODE 3, etc

**Comment by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on 2018-10-17**:
Haven't tried `ParameterService` yet so I actually don't know what they are for... might be a solution.